# Error Handing in Powershell pipe

Tags: powershell, error-handling, try-catch

How can I catch (suppress) an error within a powershell expression?

I am trying to use get-ChildItem to iterate over the files in a directory and extract some information.

```
get-ChildItem "c:\test\" -Recurse  | % { $_.Name + " ==> " + (try{(([xml] (Get-Content $_.FullName)).DocumentElement.TagName)} catch{"not xml"})  }
```

I know I could rewrite this not to use the pipe, and catch the error that way, but is it possible make this a one liner?

The above returns "try : The term 'try' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the
spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the error happens during `Get-Content`, then call it with `-ErrorAction Ignore` or `-ErrorAction SilentlyContinue`. If it happens while accessing the properties of the result of `Get-Content`, then instead of using dot notation, use `Select-Object` so you can use `-ErrorAction` on each of those:

```psh
get-ChildItem "c:\test\" -Recurse  | % { $_.Name + " ==> " + ((([xml] (Get-Content $_.FullName -ea Ignore)) | Select-Object -ExpandProperty DocumentElement -ea Ignore | Select-Object -ExpandProperty TagName -ea Ignore))  }
```

You could also [use a `trap` statement](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847742.aspx) somewhere outside of this one-liner, not sure if that counts as a one-liner still.

My recommendation is to not get hung up on something being a one-liner though. Note that pipelines don't need to be one-liners. `%` is `ForEach-Object` and the scriptblock you are passing to it can be multiple lines, complete with `try`/`catch`, `if` statements, etc.